# Install PhpMyAdmin on nginx - on every domain?

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I installed nginx with php and mysql. The problem is that I have no default domain site/file in "sites-available". I want to configure /phpmyadmin to be accessible from every domain. After the installation though, I see the error 404, how can I fix this?

Comment: Does it need to appear to be on that domain, or can you do a forward to a single domain?

Comment: it should be reacheable from any-domain.com/phpmyadmin path

Comment: any-domain.com is pointed to the nginx server of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thought is I'd just include a location block that allows access to phpMyAdmin in each Nginx server/site config file. However since you [have to tell phpMyAdmin the URL it's installed on](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#basic-settings) I don't think that will work.

I think you may have to install it separately on each domain, unless someone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: `PmaAbsoluteUri` is not required, it's optional and only of real use in very specific situations where phpMyAdmin can't automatically determine the path. So I think your suggestion is a good one, omitting the PmaAbsoluteUri directive entirely from `config.inc.php`.